# Streaming videos from ubuntu-server

Tags: server, video, streaming

## How can I stream mp4 videos the simplest way?

I just want a simple way to stream some series to my laptop or phone while I am at home. The videos are all on my ubuntu server. I tried using [minidlna](https://github.com/azatoth/minidlna) but even tho accessing it over the browser (10.0.0.x:8200) worked streaming did not. For the client I used vlc but it couldn't connect to the server. [I did these steps in vlc](https://codeyarns.com/2015/01/25/how-to-use-vlc-as-dlna-client/) 
and I used following tutorial for the [minidlna setup.](https://mylinuxramblings.wordpress.com/2016/02/19/mini-how-to-installing-minidlna-in-ubuntu/)
[image]

After some searching I found [mediatomb](http://mediatomb.cc/) but this didn't work for me either. But at least vlc did not give me an error. Now I have added the server but I can't do anything with it. Double clicking, right-click play etc. does nothing.
[image]

So how can I stream my videos to my devices? Preferably over the browser because I am sick of vlc..

Comment: Plex Media Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could recommend you with [Plex Media Server](https://www.plex.tv/features/).

They ship with some HTML5 player, that works with any modern browser (including mobiles).